# grub_file_filters not found after Ubuntu 20.04 LTS upgrade, all known methods don't work

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I attempted to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 this morning. After reboot, a `symbol 'grub_file_filters' not found` error was reported.

I googled and tried the two popular methods which I found, but none of them succeeded. The same error stuck every time I rebooted the system

The operations I applied are shown below, wish could help to find out the root cause and solution:

---

**1. Repair by a livecd**

My `/boot` is an independent partition so I mounted it as an extra step based on the solution what I found. The whole operations sequence is

```
% sudo su
 
% mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt
% mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
% mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
% mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
% mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
% mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/boot
 
% chroot /mnt
% grub-install /dev/sdb
% update-grub

% exit
% umount /mnt/boot
% umount /mnt/dev/pts
% umount /mnt/dev
% umount /mnt/proc
% umount /mnt/sys
% umount /mnt
 
% reboot
```

---

**2. Boot-repair**

I doubt what this did is similar to the operation sequence in part 1. The whole log is a little bit long so I uploaded it to https://0bin.net/paste/aChHYcRK#h2E3oydL5mm6JxbVmBAOQgpKkax4nHHXuDCFgOm77qp

---

**3. insmod**

In the grub rescure console, I tried

```
grub rescure> insmod (hd1,2)/grub/i386-pc/linux.mod
error: symbol `grub_file_filters' not found.
grub rescure> ls (hd1,2)/grub/
./ ../ gfxblacklist.txt unicode.pf2 i386-pc/ locale/ fonts/ grubenv grub.cfg
```

---

Please kindly to help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. In BIOS I found the preset setup sequence is my Win10 (/dev/sda) -> Linux (/dev/sdb). Having reordered the sequence and put my Linux partition in the first, I can see the grub now.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on Azure VM 18.04LTS to 20.04 LTS upgrade. Fixing the error once you get this is not easy. After playing around with different cloned images and upgrade options, I found that if you select N to the prompt about auto-remove obsolete packages (towards the end of the release upgrade process) then this doesn't happen and the upgrade is successful.